# Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Tags: r

I am defining a function and trying to plot it for `x > max{b1,b2}`:

```
b1<-1
b2<-2
b<-1
l<-1
fn <- function(x,b1,b2,b,l){
         result <- b/x * ((1-(sqrt(1-(b1/x)^l)*sqrt(1-(b2/x)^l)))^(- 1/l))
         return(result)
          } 
fn1 <- fn(x,b1,b2,b,l)
x<-seq(3,20,0.1)
plot(x,fn1,type="l")
```

It's working for these values but when I am changing x as follows 
x<-seq(3,100,0.1), it's showing an error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Can you suggest what is the mistake here? How it can be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what operation do you want after the b/x term, but It reads the [ ] as an index, try:

```
fn <- function(x,b1,b2,b,l){
  result <- b/x * (1-(sqrt(1-(b1/x)^l)*sqrt(1-(b2/x)^l)))**(- 1/l)
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you can see above, I have changed the code accordingly but still the error is coming. Any idea why is this happening? Is it because of x?

Comment: The vector x is defined after executing function fn, wich requires x. It looks like it's using a previous definition of x. Try define it before the function

Answer (score 0):

the results line in your function has improper syntax. it should be as follows

```
result <- b/x*(1-(sqrt(1-(b1/x)^l)*sqrt(1-(b2/x)^l)))*(- 1/l)
```

Note the differences:

- no `[ ]` are used as they have a different meaning than `( )` in R.
- multiplications `*` have been fixed throughout

Comment: Thank you very much. I have corrected the code as per your suggestion but still the error is coming while plotting this function for x > 3 (as b2=3). Do you know what is wrong here?

Comment: As @Tur mentioned in his comments, you need to define `x` before calling your function.